# Lenovo laptop with Windows 10 stuck on battery saver mode

Tags: windows-10, laptop, battery

I have a Lenovo laptop that's a few years old, which has Windows 10 installed. A few weeks ago, with no obvious cause, it got stuck in perma-battery saver mode - if I click the battery icon in the taskbar, the power mode button says "Battery saver" and is grayed out so I can't click it, even when the laptop is plugged in and regardless of the actual battery level (which is reported correctly, and the laptop charges completely normally and has a perfectly normal battery life, as far as I've been able to tell).

In the control panel power options, I still have the "Balanced" plan selected and all the options are what I chose, but they seem to be overridden by some other set of settings that I'm assuming the battery saver mode is responsible for - I've set the lid close action to sleep, for instance, and that's still selected in the power options, but since this happened closing the lid has caused it to hibernate instead, which is pretty bad since this laptop has always completely refused to properly restore from hibernation when not plugged in if it's been hibernating for too long (it just shuts down again on the Lenovo logo screen when it tries to boot).

I've of course restarted it multiple times, as well as disabling and reenabling both of the battery drivers shown in the device manager, but to no avail. I also turned off battery saver mode altogether in the settings app, but it's still on battery saver.

Anyone know what's going on, or how I can get rid of battery saver mode?

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this issue? I'm seeing the same problem but it appears the Lenovo Power Management application was not ported to Windows 8.1 or Windows 10, but instead embedded in the firmware, and can't find a way forward.

Comment: @Melikoth Unfortunately not. It actually fixed itself briefly after a Windows update this summer (or at least the sleep issue did), but then reappeared later, and by now I've switched laptops. I hope you figure it out, though!

Answer (score 1):

it's a lenovo setting that is over-riding the windows settings. you need the lenovo power management application and then the battery settings icon.

Answer (score 0):

I've had that problem, too. I ended up dismantling the laptop, remove the battery briefly. That worked.

I've since found out that the following sequence works.

1. Let the battery charge up to 100%. (not 95%, so you may have to discharge to 90% and let it charge to 100%).
2. Use the full power off - windows 10, hold SHIFT whilst you clik Shutdown.
3. Then briefly touch the power button and just as it starts, press and HOLD the power button down for >30 seconds. It aborts the power-up after a few seconds, but keep holding it. This activates the Total Poweroff, which is what service technicians have to do before removing/installing battery/motherboard and suchlike.
4. Look hopefully to the sky and power up again.